# Prayer leader does not mention מלך in blessing - should I not say אמן

Tags: halacha, blessing, text, amen

[Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 214](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.214.1?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=en&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) says

> כל ברכה שאין בה הזכרת שם ומלכות אינה ברכה
>
> Any blessing which does not mention Hashem's name and Kingship is not
> a blessing.

If a prayer leader in a blessing does not enunciate **מלך** העולם are there sources  that would justify me in not answering אמן?

Comment: He definitely didn’t say it, or you just didn’t hear it?

Comment: Your source is pretty clear. What are you unsure about?

Comment: @Chatzkel He mumbled something like "mecholom" but not even that was clear.

Comment: אל תפרוש מן הצבור

Comment: The tzibbur are answering amen to a berocho levatolo and I should not separate from them?!

Comment: I thought you referred to Reconstructionist Judaism; they don't believe in a conscious deity and therefore say "ruach ha'olam."